# Grouping quantities by price

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I have a mysql table like this

```
 id |code|price|quantity
 1  |0001|10.00|1
 2  |0001|10.00|1
 3  |0001|15.00|3
 4  |0001|15.00|1
 5  |0002| 5.00|2
 6  |0002| 5.00|1
```

Using the functions `concat` and `group_concat` I got this result:

```
SELECT code, group_concat( CONCAT( quantity, 'x', FORMAT(price, 2 ))SEPARATOR '+' ) AS sales
FROM detalle_sales
GROUP BY code

code|sales
0001|1x10,00+1x10,00+3x15.00+1x15.00
0002|2x5.00+1x5.00
```

How can I group the quantities by the price using mysql?

```
code|sales
0001|2x10.00+4x15.00
0002|3x5.00
```

I've done it by php but when the sales field is too long, the result is truncated and gives an inaccurate value.

Comment: group_concat has a length limit (1024 chars by default). If you need to produce long strings with it, then [raise the limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) or DON'T do the concatenation in the db - do it in client-side code

Comment: I may not understand the question correctly, but can you just change "GROUP BY code" to "GROUP BY code, price" ... your output will change to code|price|sales, and the quantity x price will only contain prices that match the column "price"  ... but that's what you want though, right?

Comment: I would do it in two phases - group by price and summing and then printing using what you wrote

Answer (score 0):

You need a subquery that groups all the rows with the same price together, then a main query that performs the `GROUP_CONCAT` by `code`.

```
SELECT code, group_concat( CONCAT( quantity, 'x', FORMAT(price, 2 ))SEPARATOR '+' ) AS sales
FROM (
    SELECT code, price, SUM(quantity) as quantity
    FROM detalle_sales
    GROUP by code, price) AS subq
GROUP BY code
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9cccd/1)

Answer (score 0):

While I consider it a not-so-good idea to create this sort of format in the DB, here is how it goes:

```
SELECT code, group_concat( CONCAT( total, 'x', FORMAT(price, 2 ))SEPARATOR '+' ) AS sales
FROM (
     SELECT 
       code, price,
       SUM(quantity) AS total
     FROM detalle_sales
     GROUP BY code, price
) AS baseview
GROUP BY code
```